# how to if and elif this code for print "impossible"(python)

Tags: python

This is my code -

```
"""NumDays"""
from datetime import date
def cal_date(day1, month1, day2, month2):
    """process"""
    d0 = date(2017, month1, day1)
    d1 = date(2017, month2, day2)
    delta = abs(d1 - d0)
    print(delta.days)
cal_date(int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()))
```

if day out of range for month i want to print "impossible" but i don't have any idea.

Comment: Does this even run? You're taking in 4 arguments to `cal_date`, but define it as only having 3???

Comment: i have 4.i have it all

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try-except block to detect if there's an error for a specific day in a month. Here is an example:

```
try:
  d=date(2019, 9, 31)
except:
  print("impossible")
```

You can rewrite your code this way:

```
    from datetime import date
    def cal_date(day1, month1, day2, month2):
        """process"""
        try:
            d0 = date(2560, month1, day1)
            d1 = date(2560, month2, day2)
        except:
            print("impossible")
            return

        delta = abs(d1 - d0)
        print(delta.days)
    cal_date(int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input()))
```